# How to make the background image fixed in the input box

Tags: css, background-image

As you can see in the following snapshot, there is a small icon at the right most side of the input box, when the user keeps typing in the input box, the icon starts to move, is there a way to keep it fixed in current position?

```
input.fillHoverIndicator{
   background-image:url('../../images/msg_info_grey.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   padding-right:16px;
   background-position:right;
}
```

[image]

HTML

```
<input name="instance/logical.name"  class="fillHoverIndicator" id="X26" style="width:     100%; height: 19px;" onkeydown="cfKeyDown(event, 'X26');
    " onkeyup="cfKeyUp(event, 'X26');" onclick="handleOnClick(this, event);" onfocus="cbOnFocus(this, event);" onblur="cbOnBlur(this, event);
applyToSameControl(this);
  " onchange="handleOnChange(this, event);" type="text" maxLength="2147483647"     ButtonId="" dvdVar="" datachangeevent="" scripttype="comfill" getValue="function      getComboValue()
{
....
  return this.value
}" 
for="X26" idFill="9" PopupSubformWidth="333" PopupSubformEnabled="1"          PopupSubformInput="logical.name" PopupSubformFormat="popup.ci.info" tooltipHeight="209" tooltipWidth="333" tooltipUrl="popupsubform?hfformat=popup.ci.info&hfinput=logical.name&xScale=4.5&thread=1" value="1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"/>
```

Comment: Icon doesn't move in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJf7c/)??

Answer (score 0):

**now define** to **according** `width`, `height` , `line-height`, and `padding`

**as like this**

```
input.fillHoverIndicator{
width:xxx; // according to your design
height:xxx; // according to your design
line-heiht:xxx; // according to your design
padding-right:xxx; // according to your design
background:url ('../../images/msg_info_grey.png')  no-repeat right top; // according to your design
}
```

Comment: How come with width, height and line-height defined, the icon could be fixed in current position...I tried anyways, no luck.

Comment: @Even According to your code http://jsfiddle.net/DJf7c/1/ and now remove !important tag in css than first you remove inline css in you html part ..